# How to send email using Google OAuth (via SMTP)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, gmail

Have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977961/gmail-3-legged-oauth-access-zend-mail-protocol-exception) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602680/how-to-implement-gmail-oauth-api-to-send-email-especially-via-smtp) and using example from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/PhpSampleCode).

However, I am still having difficulty in sending emails as a verified Google user using OAuth.  I have the valid OAuth tokens, secrets, and xoauth token as well.

My code to send the email:

```
$authenticateParams = array('XOAUTH', $initClientRequestEncoded); 

$smtp = new Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', 587, array(
"AUTH" => $authenticateParams, 'ssl' => 'tls')); 

try {
   // Create a new mail object
   $mail = new Zend_Mail();

   $mail->setFrom("aaaaa@gmail.com");
   $mail->addTo("bbbbb@gmail.com");
   $mail->setSubject("Your account has been created");

   $email = "Thank you for registering!";

   $mail->setBodyText($email);
   $mail->send();

} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo "error sending email . <BR>" . $e;
}
```

But this seems to send an anonymous email and not as the user authenticated.  If I do:

```
$smtp = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', array('AUTHENTICATE' => $authenticateParams, 'ssl' => 'tls')); 
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($smtp);
```

I get: exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '5.5.1 Authentication Required.

I'm sure it's just a case of getting the mail transport smtp params right, but the documentation for sending SMTP emails is non-existent and I can't find any code examples for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following blog posts which will show you where you went wrong.

[google smtp oauth2 authentication](http://www.fanmix.com/blog/google-smtp-oauth2-authentication/)

[send mail with gmail smtp and xoauth](http://piecewiseinc.blogspot.com/2013/02/send-mail-with-gmail-smtp-and-xoauth.html)